# Query with two dates in mongoose and return documents that match?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a mongoose collection who's schema looks like this:

```
"date_from": {type: Date, required: true},
"date_to": {type: Date, required: true},
"num_guests": {type: Number, required: true},
"children": {type: Number, required: true},
```

Now I have to search for documents that are between the range of "date_from" to "date_to" based on the dates I provide.

Now, I figured out this bit of code which does most of what I need.

```
 model.find({_id: req.body._id,
                $and:[{date_from: {$gte: "2020-04-26T06:50:45.079+00:00",$lte: "2020-05-01T06:50:45.079+00:00"}},
{date_to: {$lte: "2020-05-01T06:50:45.079+00:00"}}]
            })
```

but I ran into a problem with this code when: In my collection there is a document which has `"date_from": "2020-04-04"` to `"date_to":"2020-04-08"`. Now when I query with `$gte: "2020-04-03"` and `$lte: "2020-04-09"`, I get the document but when I change it to `$gte: "2020-04-05"` and `$lte: "2020-04-09"`, I receive an empty array. But I still need to get that document because technically it is still within `$gte: "2020-04-05"` and `$lte: "2020-04-09"`. How would I do that?

This scenario can be best explained by:

I have a hotel room booked for 12-04-2020 to 24-04-2020 now if someone looks up all bookings between 16-04-2020 to 20-04-2020 then they should see the booking that has been made between 12 to 24.

I looked through the other related questions to find an answer but I did not find anything much.

Comment: Your existing $and query select documents that have both endpoints between the given dates.  That is not tru for the document you mentioned.  Perhaps you meant to query for date_to >= first_date and date_from <= second_date?

Comment: Most of your question talks about dates but the actual query uses times. Dates and times are not the same; which one are you looking to query by?